# Concatenating dict values, which are lists

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, dictionary

Suppose I have the following dict object:

```
test = {}
test['tree'] = ['maple', 'evergreen']
test['flower'] = ['sunflower']
test['pets'] = ['dog', 'cat']
```

Now, if I run `test['tree'] + test['flower'] + test['pets']`, I get the result:

```
['maple', 'evergreen', 'sunflower', 'dog', 'cat']
```

which is what I want.

However, suppose that I'm not sure what keys are in the dict object but I know all the values will be lists.  Is there a way like `sum(test.values())` or something I can run to achieve the same result?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You *nearly* gave the answer in the question:
`sum(test.values())` only fails because it assumes by default that you want to add the items to a start value of `0`—and of course you can't add a `list` to an `int`.  However, if you're explicit about the start value, it will work:

```
 sum(test.values(), [])
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!  Good to know I was on the right track.  This one liner is the shortest and most readable.  In certain settings which require more readability I might also use Psidom's answer.

Answer (score 14):

Use `chain` from `itertools`:

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(test.values()))
# ['sunflower', 'maple', 'evergreen', 'dog', 'cat']
```

Comment: Not sure about why the downvote, but this is my solution too. An alternative is `list(chain(*test.values()))`

Comment: for large dicts the `chain.from_iterable` is probably more efficient as it doesn't have to materialise them as an args tuple first

Answer (score 13):

One liner (*assumes no specific ordering is required*):

```
>>> [value for values in test.values() for value in values]
['sunflower', 'maple', 'evergreen', 'dog', 'cat']
```

Comment: I have been working with python for a bit now and I'm sometimes blown away how unreadable list comprehensions are.

Comment: @ospahiu could you please explain how your code works? For instance,  `[x for x in val for val in a.values()]` won't work, but why? Here `a={'a':[1,2,3],'b'=[4,5,6],'c'=[7,8,9]}
`

Answer (score 5):

You could use [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) and [`operator.concat`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/operator.html#operator.concat) (I'm assuming you're using Python 3) like this:

```
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> from operator import concat
>>> reduce(concat, test.values())
['maple', 'evergreen', 'sunflower', 'dog', 'cat']
```

Comment: Note that you might have to set a default value if the list is empty: `reduce(concat, test.values(), [])`

Answer (score 1):

Another easy option using using `numpy.hstack`:

```
import numpy as np

>>> np.hstack(list(test.values()))
array(['maple', 'evergreen', 'sunflower', 'dog', 'cat'], dtype='<U9')
```

Comment: easier : `np.hstack(test.values())`

Comment: True, modified accordingly! In the future though, numpy stacks have to be passed as a sequence. Hence the ```list()```.