# How do we get <generator object .<locals>.<genexpr> data from list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

```
testdict = {'1':[1,1],'2':[2,2]}
test = []
for i in testdict:
    test.append(k for k in i)
```

If we print `test` for the current scenario, we get output like -

`[<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7f8216183d00>, <generator object <genexpr> at 0x7f82161090f8>]`

How do we get the actual data? Can we do an append to a list comprehension?

Comment: `k for k in i` is a generator expression that you're appending to your list. What's your expected output?

Comment: @Kasramvd I want to append data using list comprehension to an empty list defined outside the for loop.

Comment: Which data? you're looping over the dictionary keys which are strings. Even if you add all the `k` variables to the list you'll end up with all the characters in keys.

Comment: Data from the list.

Comment: Let's say I am looping over queryset and want to add data from it to an empty list

Comment: It's getting more and more obscure :). Please update your question with a comprehensive and detailed information about your input and output data. However, If you want to concatenate values you can use answers from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41455975/concatenating-dict-values-which-are-lists (except the accepted answer, never use that!)

Answer (score 0):

When you append a generator expression, you are not appending the values extracted if you were to iterate the generator expression. You are only appending the lazy iterator object.

What you most likely want to do is to extract all values from your dictionary. You can do this using `itertools.chain` without resorting to an explicit `for` loop:

```
from itertools import chain

testdict = {'1': [1,1], '2': [2,2]}

res = list(chain.from_iterable(testdict.values()))

print(res)
[1, 1, 2, 2]
```

Note that dictionary items are not considered to be ordered (unless you are on Python 3.7+). Therefore, you should consider using `OrderedDict` or `sorted(testdict.items())` to define the order of your input.